# Discord.js take a user id from voiceStateUpdate

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get the id of the user entering the channel. I have to save the time spent inside the vocal channels. Can you help me out?

```
client1.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember, id) => {
    let newUserChannel = newMember.channelID
    let date = new Date()
    let oldUserChannel = oldMember.channelID //NON RIMUOVERE
    let userid = ???
 
    if(newUserChannel === newUserChannel && newUserChannel != undefined) 
    { 
        // Entra
        console.log("Entra nel canale: "+newUserChannel);
        console.log(date.getHours(),":", date.getMinutes())
        //console.log(userInfo())
    }
    else{
        // Esce
        console.log("Esce dal canale");
    }
 });
```

Solved in this way:

```
//Save join & quit event
client1.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    let newUserChannel = newMember.channelID
    let date = new Date()
    let oldUserChannel = oldMember.channelID //NON RIMUOVERE
    let userid = newMember.member.user.id
    if(newUserChannel === newUserChannel && newUserChannel != undefined) 
    { 
        // Entra
        console.log("Entra nel canale: "+newUserChannel);
        console.log(date.getHours(),":", date.getMinutes())
        console.log(userid)
    }
    else{
        // Esce
        console.log("Esce dal canale");
    }
 });
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Try replacing `channelID` with `channel.id`